# How can I rotate a rectangle and position using MiniMagick?

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

I'm trying to create an overlay using `mini_magick` (Ruby wrapper for `imagemagick`) similar to the example below:

[image: example image]

I know how to draw a rectangle, and I know how to rotate, but I can't wrap my head around the coordinate system once the rotation has been applied.

So I wrote the following:

```rb
x = original_icon.width / 2
y = 0 # or should it be -10 so it's off the canvas?
width = 100
height = 20
result = original_icon.combine_options do |c|
  c.fill('#FF0000')
  c.draw "rotate -45 rectangle #{x},#{y},#{width},#{height}"
end
```

However, things get odd fast after the rotate -45. It seems positioning has completely gone out the window.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Use [`path` drawing command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php). It might be easier than attempting rotation and translation, as you already know the expected coordinates of the shape.

Comment: @emcconville thanks so much for bringing this to my attention!